# How do I request for the device lock or biometric authentication pin/password in AOSP?

Tags: android, passwords, android-source, lockscreen, applocker

I would like the device lock password to be used for including an app lock as part of the OS. I am unable to find the API that lets me request for the device password which when successfully authenticated would open the app.
I am trying this in Android 12 AOSP.

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Biometric Library for the same, https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth